How am I supposed to discuss comment deletion with mods?
Some comments of mine on a question got removed. I disagree with the removal so I flagged the question asking why the comments got removed.  My flag got declined with the reason:

flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

How am I supposed to discuss comment deletion with mods?

Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. You should not expect them to be around forever.

@Mast I'm not discussing here about the comment deletion  but how to raise the issue to the mods

You don't, that's not how comments work. If anything requires further clarification, you leave a new comment. Is there any value keeping the obsolete one around over posting a new one that is hopefully better tuned to the current situation?

@Mast then if your comment is an answer, you post it as an answer. That's not how comments work.

You're not?
In general, comment deletions are not really a major issue. In this case the comment already served its purpose - you got the feedback you requested and there's literally no additional purpose to the comment.
Any further clarifications probably belong first on your question, then elsewhere. That said, I'm not entirely sure that looking at the question in question that it'd help.
I also feel like we spent more words on discussing a comment removal than the actual comment, on a post that's already been handled by the community so.. unless the comment is earthshatteringly insightful, and you NEED to see it to improve your post measurably, there's nothing to discuss.

Thanks, I'm not discussing here about that particular instance of comment deletion but how to raise the issue to the mods. By "You're not?", is that some rhetorical question and in fact you mean that users are not supposed to discuss comment deletion with mods? Just to be clear.

I mean, in general, there's nothing to discuss.  We'll review flags on comments, act accordingly, and generally people are cool with it.

@FranckDernoncourt what is the issue? Looking at your question and your comments, we don't know what the issue is. Do you want them to be reinstated? Do you want to see what they were? Do you want to suggest for comments not to be deleted anymore? If you want to discuss something, usually it belongs to meta or chat (if it's not post-worthy)

If your post answers the question, then post it as an answer not a comment.
If you're after clarification of some point, then the comment is redundant once the clarification is made and deletion is just cleaning up.
Comments are ephemeral.

I didn't mean to discuss about the comment deletion itself but here is my issue that happened several times: I post a question, someone leave a comment criticizing it / raising some concern, I reply to it, then my reply gets removed while the comment criticizing it is kept, which makes it appear to future readers/voters as if the concern was valid.

E.g. on https://archive.is/SIk9X, I had replied to the comment, but my reply got removed, making it appear as if I (the OP) agree with the comment and the closure. This issue happens much more often on SU than other SE sites.
